# Monitor a directory for changes and FTP a file to a server

Tags: linux, ftp, cron

I am looking for a specific command/script for a cron job I want to perform.

Basically, I have a WordPress website that when you fill in a form writes a png file to a folder. usually with a name like 5d5bb3f4cdcad3.49988477.png.

Basically what I want to do is when a new file is detected in the folder ftp that file to an ftp server. Or preferably email the file, the server does run cPanel so I actually don't know if there is a command function for emailing.

I am used to working with powershell so linux is not my mother-tongue.

Comment: What have you already tried? Please show us what your research got you – I'm sure there are some answers around for syncing directories via FTP under Linux.

Comment: I have found inotifywait as a tool to use with linux. My problem is that on the server I don't think I have permissions to install software.
https://superuser.com/questions/956311/continuously-detect-new-files-with-inotify-tools-within-multiple-directories-r

Comment: That makes everything much more complicated of course. Is it a shared web server space that you've rented? Perhaps you could explain a little bit more about the environment and what you've already tried. Do you have an ftp command available (e.g. `lftp`)? See https://askubuntu.com/a/758651/17529

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I don't think cron on its own is going to be useful for you.

You might want to look at a tool called `rsync`. It can be set up to look for new files in a location and then move these. You can even move the files across ssh to another server using

```
rsync -v --ignore-existing -e ssh /home/localuser/ remoteuser@X.X.X.X:/home
```

I would then schedule a cron job to run every minute/5 minutes to call this function to copy the files where you need.

For more information on rsync, you can use the `man rsync` command on linux, but there are lots of great tutorials online for rsync which might be easier to get to grips with.

Comment: I guess your example would be better if it didn't point to a file but a source directory. Also, rsync does not support FTP, so it's not a solution for the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't find a direct solution to my problem I found an alternative.

My problem was when the files where being written it was generating a link that would send via email and the link wasn't being called in PHP properly and you couldn't display the file in your web browser. That is why I needed to send it through ftp or email the file.

I found an alternative, I was using a form plugin and it was generating signature image files, I found a function of the plugin to generate a PDF file with all the details and it works properly.

Case closed I guess lol.